# PonyORM with mixins with custom hash

Tags: ponyorm

I have a (in this case) mixin class that defines its own **hash** and **eq**. When mixing this into a Pony Entity evil things happen:

```
from pony.orm import Database, Optional, Required

db = Database()


class RoleMixin:
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.name)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.name == other or self.name == getattr(other, "name", None)

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.permissions:
            return self.permissions

        return set()


class Role(db.Entity, RoleMixin):
    name = Required(str, unique=True)
    description = Optional(str, nullable=True)
    permissions = Optional(str, nullable=True)


db.bind("sqlite", ":memory:", create_db=True)
db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)


role = Role(name="admin")
print(role)
```

And when running this:

```
  File "/Users/jwag/fs/py3.7env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pony/utils/utils.py", line 78, in cut_traceback
    reraise(exc_type, exc, full_tb)
  File "/Users/jwag/fs/py3.7env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pony/utils/utils.py", line 95, in reraise
    try: raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/jwag/fs/py3.7env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pony/utils/utils.py", line 61, in cut_traceback
    try: return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jwag/fs/py3.7env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 4721, in __init__
    entity._get_from_identity_map_(pkval, 'created', undo_funcs=undo_funcs, obj_to_init=obj)
  File "/Users/jwag/fs/py3.7env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 4416, in _get_from_identity_map_
    cache.objects.add(obj)
  File "/Users/jwag/fs/flask-security/flask_security/ponydbg.py", line 8, in __hash__
    return hash(self.name)
  File "<string>", line 2, in __get__
  File "/Users/jwag/fs/py3.7env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pony/utils/utils.py", line 78, in cut_traceback
    reraise(exc_type, exc, full_tb)
  File "/Users/jwag/fs/py3.7env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pony/utils/utils.py", line 95, in reraise
    try: raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/jwag/fs/py3.7env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pony/utils/utils.py", line 61, in cut_traceback
    try: return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jwag/fs/py3.7env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 2278, in __get__
    value = attr.get(obj)
  File "/Users/jwag/fs/py3.7env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pony/orm/core.py", line 2286, in get
    vals = obj._vals_
AttributeError: _vals_
```

Since Pony is using meta-programming - I can't really figure out where/why it is using **hash** and why defining it confuses it so much.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You may have an '@classmethod' decorator before your mixin class methods.

```
class RoleMixin:
@classmethod
def __hash__(cls):
    return hash(cls.name)

@classmethod
def __eq__(cls, other):
    return cls.name == other or cls.name == getattr(other, "name", None)

@classmethod
def get_permissions(cls):
    if cls.permissions:
        return cls.permissions

    return set()
```

Comment: can you add a sample output to show this method working?

Comment: the output: Role[new:1]